# Use Javascript to keep track of a function unique to each div

Tags: php, javascript, html, function

So here is my goal, i need to be able to determine what the color of the background of a div that a user clicks on. Each div has a function that determines its background. How would i use javascript to keep track of the functions or would it be easier to send that data to the url so i can compare it to a predetermined code?

```
<?php "session_start" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<?php

$cols = array(

"#000000",
"#FFFFFF",
"#0000FF",
"#008000",
"#800080",
"#FF0000",
"#FFFF00",
"#DD7500",
"#4FD5D6",
"#CD6090", 
);

function getRandomColor1() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}





function getRandomColor2() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];    
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}



function getRandomColor3() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor4() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor5() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand]; 
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}



function getRandomColor6() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor7() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor8() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor9() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}


function getRandomColor10() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
unset($cols[$rand]);
return $rand_col;
}




?> 



<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#full {
height: 300px;
width: 750px;
border: 3px solid #999; 
margin: 0 auto;

} 



#boxone1 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor1(); ?>; ;
float: left;
} 

#boxone2 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor2(); ?>;  
float: left;
} 
#boxone3 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor3(); ?>;  
float: left;
} 
#boxone4 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor4(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 
#boxone5 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor5(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 


#boxtwo1 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor6(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 

#boxtwo2 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor7(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 
#boxtwo3 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor8(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 
#boxtwo4 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor9(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 
#boxtwo5 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?php echo getRandomColor10(); ?>; 
float: left;
} 

</style>






<body>

<div id="full">

<div id="boxone1" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxone2" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxone3" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxone4" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxone5" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxtwo1" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxtwo2" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxtwo3" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxtwo4" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

<div id="boxtwo5" onClick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

More or less, im wondering how i could collect the order in which colors are selected and compare them to a predetermined pattern. Would it be better to do this through js or through posting it in the url?
Either way, could someone demonstrate how it could be done?

Comment: I can hear a DRY screaming when I look at this. Why do you need functions in the first place, if all they do is duplicate the code? Why not just make a single function that will take div id as a param?

Comment: the functions each remove one color from the array. They make it so each color appears only once and in a random location.

Comment: You can do all that with one function.

Comment: But they remove the color from the same array.  In other words, it doesn't matter if you call getRandomColor3 or getRandomColor5, they all remove from `$cols[$rand]`, so there's no reason to have multiple functions.

Comment: oh okay well ill remove the multiple copies then. I didn't realize that i could do that all with one function. I'm new to functions and php in general

Comment: How would I make determine the background color of each div then if there is only one function?

Comment: Your (one) function generates random colors for each div on the server (which then sends it to the client and you view the page, so you can think of that as "just before the page loads").  Once the page loads it has those random colors on it, and you can use a little bit of Javascript (like the bit in my answer) to get that color and send it back.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could explain your end goal.  I know you want to get a list of colors, and the order they were clicked, but what do you then want to do with that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just add them to an array inside a click handler (using jQuery, but if you don't like jQuery I can rewrite it without):

```
var clickedColors = []
$('div').click(function() {
    clickedColors.push($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
});
```

Then for the comparison part I'd just use JS logic.  You might want to check out the Underscore.js library, as it has a lot of great functions for working with arrays.

*** * Edit * ***

Or, if you want a "least Javascript possible" approach, you could just send the background color through with onClick action you already have.  You can do this by changing:

```
window.location='?name='+this.id
```

to:

```
window.location='?name='+this.id+'&color='+this.style.backgroundColor
```

This will give you a "color" parameter on the server-side which should have the background color of the div that got clicked.

*** * Edit #2 * ***

After chatting with the OP it seemed that the best approach (given their lack of Javascript knowledge) was to try and do as little Javascript as possible.  We therefore settled on:

1. putting the colors inside hidden inputs next to the div
2. putting a form around the hidden input and div
3. changing the onclick code to submit the form

So now the user clicks, that div's form gets submitted, the hidden input next to the div tells the server what color got clicked, and the OP is free to do whatever they want with the color on the server-side/in PHP.

Comment: i don't know js logic or underscore.js, haven't used any javasript or any libraries. So would i put this in an external js page or put it on my main page?

Comment: Hmmm ... it seems like you're relatively new to PHP, so trying to tackle Javascript might be a bit much.  The "right" way for an experienced coder to solve this problem would be to use Javascript, but for you I honestly think you might be better off just using PHP.  You're already hitting the server/PHP side with every click anyway, so I'd recommend just modifying your onclick to send the color to the server.  I'll edit my answer with how to do that.

Comment: still so confused by this method... sorry. So the "window.location='?name='+this.id+'&color='+this.style.backgroundColor" determines the background color, what determines the order of clicked colors?

Comment: could you explain how what i need to change in each section of the code to make it work?

Comment: The javascript isnt working, its coming up with an error. The window.location='?name='+this.id+'&color='+this.style.backgroundColor isnt outputting any color... Could you write out each step so i can actually understand it?

Comment: Sure.  So what you've got right now is a bunch of divs, and each of those divs has an "onclick" attribute.  That means that if anyone clicks on any of those divs, the javascript code inside the "onclick" will be run.  Before, that code would just navigate the user to the same URL they are currently on, except with '?name='+this.id (eg. "name=5") added.  What my code did was add an extra parameter, so when the user clicks on it not only will "name=" get added, but also "color=".  This means that your server-side (PHP) code can access the new "color" parameter to get what color the user clicked.

Comment: I can't really help you with the error unless you provide it.  As for the steps, they are 1) replace the code I mentioned with the code I wrote 2) write some PHP code that uses the new "color" parameter that will now be coming through.  Presumably you want to keep track of that color somehow (save it in a database?); I'm not clear on what your end goal is.

Comment: okay that makes sense... so the colors are then called by the array in the javascript instead of how it is now?

Comment: Kinda; the colors aren't really "called" by anything, they're just there on the div.  The div also has an onclick action which looks at the div's color when the div gets clicked, and that color gets sent to you when you/your PHP code when the div is clicked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13537/discussion-between-ryno-and-machineghost)

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript example of a potential solution (http://jsfiddle.net/hHXV4/1/) that I couldn't resist writing. The logic is all there if you want to follow it.

EDIT: Updated for simplicity!

```
var e,body,colors,clickOrder,count;
clickOrder = [];
colors = [
    "#000000",
    "#FFFFFF",
    "#0000FF",
    "#008000",
    "#800080",
    "#FF0000",
    "#FFFF00",
    "#DD7500",
    "#4FD5D6",
    "#CD6090"
];
count = colors.length;
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
    e = document.createElement('div');
    e.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    e.indx = i;
    e.addEventListener("click",function(){
        clickOrder.push(colors[this.indx]);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        count--;
        if(count == 0){
            alert(clickOrder.join());
        }
    });
    body.appendChild(e);
}​
```

Comment: should i do this as an external page?

Comment: and i got an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: If you were to use this answer you would put it inside a `<script>` tag on the page.  However, I wouldn't recommend using it for two reasons: 1) it uses `addEventListener`, which won't work with Internet Explorer, and 2) it doesn't help you get the color back to the server; it just replaces your existing PHP code as a pure-JS way of generating the random-colored divs (and if you aren't comfortable with JS that won't help you much).

Comment: @machineghost It's supposed to be a guide to potential way of queueing up color selections, what the user does with it afterwards is up to them. I am not out to write full solutions to all problems, I like to sometimes give people a jumping off point so they can figure out the rest themselves. As for the IE problem, easily fixed with some conditional code.